# LibreOffice Basic Macro command converting Calc cellRange to RTF/HTML

Tags: html, rtf, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

My goal is to fill a LibreOffice calc sheet, and silently send a cell range by email when the user clicks the send-off button (and once more to confirm).

So there is three part to this.

- A push button with a request to confirm. (Easy and done.)
- Select Cell Range and turn it into rich text format (Haven't yet found)
- Send rich text email from within the sheet. (Will tackle the "silent" part later)

I tried copying the range to the clipboard with unoService but it seemed over-complicated and full of errors.

Here's what I have:

```vb
''''Send by e-mail enriched text

Sub Main
    Dim Doc, Sheet, Range, Rtf, Exec as Object
End Sub

'Confirm it
Sub SendTableApproval
    If MsgBox ("Ready to email?", MB_YESNO + MB_DEFBUTTON2) = IDYES Then
        CopyTable()
    End If
End Sub

'Copy it
Sub CopyTable
    Doc = ThisComponent
    View = Doc.CurrentController
    Frame = View.Frame
    Sheet = Doc.Sheets.getByIndex(0)
    Range = Sheet.getCellrangeByName("a1:f45")
    Exec = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")

    View.Select(Range)
    Cells = View.getTransferable()
    Exec.executeDispatch(Frame, ".uno:Deselect", "", 0, array())   
    'SimpleMailTo(Cells)
End Sub

'Mail it
Sub SimpleMailTo(body)
    Dim launcher as object
    Dim eAddress, eSubject, eBody, aHTMLanchor as string
    launcher = CreateUnoService("com.sun.star.system.SystemShellExecute")
    eAddress = "tu@domo.eg"
    eSubject = "Cotidie agenda futuendane"
    eBody = body
    aHTMLanchor = "mailto:" & eAddress & "?subject=" & eSubject & "&amp;&body=" & eBody
    launcher.execute(aHTMLanchor, "", 0)
End Sub
```

I still do not know after three days of research over methods, properties, uno.

My question is, simply put, **How can I convert a transferable content to HTML/RTF?**

Comment: I would say hard to answer without seeing how the email is sent. You should add `SimpleMailTo` to your question too. Because if you submit eg rtf/html code in `body` then it will probably send just an email with that rtf/html code in it as plain text (so you see that source code in your mail). But it will not convert it into a formatted email, which obviously is what you want. So I think you might asked the wrong question: Instead of "*How can I convert a cell range to HTML/RTF?*" it should be something like "*How can I send a formatted email instead of plain text*" in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, just added. Problem is, whether or not I try to send plain text or html/rtf, I am first stuck with trying to solve the conversion issue.

Comment: The question is much clearer now with your new code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply copying and pasting into an email produces the result you are asking for.  The code on the LibreOffice side should look like this.

```
dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:Copy", "", 0, Array())
```

It sounds like you already tried this, but something didn't work.  Perhaps you could elaborate on what went wrong.

Another approach would be to [write the spreadsheet](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Saving_Spreadsheet_Documents) to a temporary HTML or XHTML file.   Then parse the temporary file to grab the part needed for the email.

AFAIK there is no such command to turn a cell range into rich text format with UNO.  To do it that way, you would need to loop through each [text range](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/text/TextRange.html) of each cell, read its formatting properties and then generate the HTML yourself.

**EDIT**:

Good idea about [XTransferable](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/datatransfer/XTransferable.html).  The following Java code adapted from [the DevGuide](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Common_Application_Features) gets an HTML string and then prints it.  I believe this would be a good solution for your needs.

```
public void displayHTMLFromClipboard()
{
    try
    {
        Object oClipboard = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext(
            "com.sun.star.datatransfer.clipboard.SystemClipboard", xContext);
        XClipboard xClipboard = (XClipboard)
            UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XClipboard.class, oClipboard);
        XTransferable xTransferable = xClipboard.getContents();
        DataFlavor[] aDflvArr = xTransferable.getTransferDataFlavors();
        System.out.println("Available clipboard formats:");
        DataFlavor aChosenFlv = null;
        for (int i=0;i<aDflvArr.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(
                "MimeType: " + aDflvArr[i].MimeType +
                " HumanPresentableName: " + aDflvArr[i].HumanPresentableName );
            if (aDflvArr[i].MimeType.equals("text/html"))
            {
                aChosenFlv = aDflvArr[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        try
        {
            if (aChosenFlv != null)
            {
                System.out.println("HTML text on the clipboard...");
                Object aData = xTransferable.getTransferData(aChosenFlv);
                String s = new String((byte[])aData, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException exc)
        {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch(com.sun.star.uno.Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If you plan to use Basic, it might be a good idea to do some research into the proper way to convert bytes.  The code I have below seems to work but is probably unreliable and unsafe, and will not work for many languages.  A few of my initial attempts crashed before this finally worked.

```
Sub DisplayClipboardData
    oClipboard = createUnoService("com.sun.star.datatransfer.clipboard.SystemClipboard")
    xTransferable = oClipboard.getContents()
    aDflvArr = xTransferable.getTransferDataFlavors()
    For i = LBound(aDflvArr) To UBound(aDflvArr)
        If aDflvArr(i).MimeType = "text/html" Then
            Dim aData() As Byte
            aData = xTransferable.getTransferData(aDflvArr(i))
            Dim s As String
            For j = LBound(aData) to UBound(aData)
                s = s & Chr(aData(j))  'XXX: Probably a bad way to do this!
            Next j
            Print(s)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

One more suggestion: Python might be a better language choice here.  In many ways, using Python with LibreOffice is easier than Java.  And unlike Basic, Python is powerful enough to comfortably handle byte strings.

Comment: Thanks! Because of your help I found out about the getTransferrable service and can now put the content of my sheet in an object. I am though now not sure what it means to have a transferrable and how to convert it to html. I would obviously like not to generate html myself but keep looking ^^'